# Geolocation API questions: $ is undefined, location load simultaneously with other HTML, and accuracy with VPNs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, api, geolocation

I would like to use a Geolocation API on the client-side to identify the user's IP and add their state to my webpage. As I am fairly new to learning Javascript and jQuery, could you assist me with my problem below?

I am receiving an error from the Console that $ is not defined – how do you suggest I solve this problem so the solution works? (see near end of script)

**Additional Issues:**

- I would like the user's state to render at the same time as the surrounding text appears –– how do I accomplish this?
- I tested the API with a VPN and found a few inaccuracies –– is it more difficult for API's to track IP (and determine their state) when the user uses a VPN to be in California vs. if they were actually in California? (*California is used as an example*)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Get User State & Display</title>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ip-geolocation-api-jquery-sdk@1.1.0/ipgeolocation.min.js"></script>
<script>
    _ipgeolocation.enableSessionStorage(true);

    var ip = sessionStorage.getItem("ip");
    var country_name = sessionStorage.getItem("country_name");
    var state_prov = sessionStorage.getItem("state_prov");
           
    if (!ip || !country_name || !country_code2) {
        _ipgeolocation.makeAsyncCallsToAPI(false);
        _ipgeolocation.setFields("country_name, state_prov");
        _ipgeolocation.getGeolocation(handleResponse);
    }

    function handleResponse(json) {
        ip = json.ip;
        country_name = json.country_name;
        state_prov = json.state_prov;
    }

    $("document").onload(function() {
        $('.state').html(json.state_prov);
    });
// I am receiving an error from the Console that $ is not defined – how do you suggest I solve this problem so the solution works?
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <p><strong>If you would like to know more about stock options in <span class="state"></span>, contact our team today!</strong></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: if you want accuracy, ask the user for permission to access [Geolocation_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API), IP geo is not at all accurate